# Website Hosting error: took too long to respond

Tags: wordpress, localhost, hosting

I developed a wordpress website on localhost but when trying to host the website i get this error. www.medina.com took too long to respond.
Search Google for medina 8080. Any idea why this is happening?
I have edited my wp_options to the site url.

Answer (score 0):

For running your website on local machine you need to use IP Address, your request is something like that

```
http://YourIPAddress:PortNo
```

If you want to use your own HostName, For that you need to put a entry in host file.